# Travis CI - Unable to run an `c` executable in makefile

Tags: c, shell, makefile, travis-ci

I've got the following Makefile which compiles, creates an executable and then executes it.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = hellomake.h
OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
    ./hellomake
```

It works perfectly on my local machine and when it builds in Travis the following error comes up.

`gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I.
hellomake.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hellomake] Error 1`

Comment: Your `hellomake` is not a binary executable. Run `file hellomake` to find out what it is. Maybe also `head -n 1 hellomake`. Something went wrong in your build.

Comment: I did that and following was the error. 
gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o -I.
hellomake.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hellomake] Error 1

Comment: @DhiwaTg Your `hellofunc.o` is from a different system (try `file hellofunc.o`). Remove it and then recompile it.

Comment: @Jens.. Ya I did the same a min ago and it works perfectly now.

Comment: The $(CFLAGS) is not the right thing to pass to the link step.  If needed, the link step needs to know about library paths `-L<pathToLibrary>`  and about which libraries `-l<libShortName>`  it does not need to know about the location of #include files `-I.`

Comment: @DhiwaTdG Ok, I made it an answer. I leave it up to you, what do do next :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hellofunc.o` is from a different system (try `file hellofunc.o`). Remove it and then recompile it.

Were you cross-compiling? Do you have a home directory mounted on different machines? Perhaps unpacking an archive made by someone else on a different architecture?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I'm setting up a continuous integration server for my project and it was a sample test on Travis-CI server.